# How to you enable taskbar administrative privileges with a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I've seen all over the internet how to use the 'secret' admin user, however I'd like something that can enable using batch, and allow my user to, for example, adjust music. 
May be a weird question but I'm because control panel, cmd & the lot are all disabled.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: `net user administrator active:yes`. You'll have to find a way to bypass that block, because either way, you need admin rights to do it.

Comment: If you could programmatically bypass UAC, every malware would just take over your computer.